# Can I automatically make a Trello list from a bunch of files?

Tags: trello, attachment, automation

I have a folder with ~360 files on Google Drive. I would like to have a list in Trello which has one card per file, with the file attached to the card. The name of the card can be the same as the name of the card.

Is there a quick way to do that, possibly using third party tools? I don't need this functionality too frequently, so I don't want to start learning their API.

Doing it per hand is very cumbersome. I managed to create all cards at once, but now I have to click each, click "Attach", then select "Google drive", and then the choice dialog is always sorted by newest, so I have to re-sort by name and scroll down through every single file on my Google drive (haven't found a way to browse by folders in the dialog) until I am at the file for that card.

Answer (score 1):

Zapier is a third-party service that connects different cloud services without writing code.  They support creating Trello cards when files are placed into a Google Drive directory:

[Connect Google Drive and Trello](https://zapier.com/zapbook/trello/google-drive/)

Depending on volume you may have to pay for service, but their free account is pretty generous.